# function to return innerhtml of clicked class in google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need a variable in Google Tagmanager which returns the innerhtml of a clicked class. Since there are more elements with this class I have to add an event listener to the classes and return the innerhtml of the clicked element.

Unfortunately my code keeps returning 'undefined'.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").foreach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    return event.innerHTML;
  })
})
```

Comment: `event` is not the dom object, either use `item` or `event.target`. Also you don't `return` data from an event listener as it doesn't return back to your code

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Changed ```return event.innerHTML``` to ```console.log(event.target.innerHTML); return true;``` which still gives an 'undefined' and nothing in the console.

Comment: If you want to use this in GTM, you should do a datalayer.push in the function inside the event handler, and then retrieve the value via GTM variables.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a variable that returns inner html of a clicked element (you don't click classes, you click elements).

1. Make a click trigger where you would use whatever CSS selector you need it to work for.
2. Make a Custom JS variable like so:

   return {{Clicked Element}}.innerHTML;
3. Now you can make a tag where you would use your trigger and your CJS variable.

No need to add your own event listeners when GTM is perfectly capable of doing it for you. While you certainly still can add your event listeners and pass the data from them to GTM through the dataLayer, you're increasing the complexity needlessly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know the options in tag manager. Unfortunately it is not that easy with elements in elements and needing to find parents, etc. But this put me in a different mind set than my previous solution and I that worked. So thanks!

Comment: Yes, generally having the clicked element and the full power of JS, you can do a lot from there. I'm glad you've solved it.